# How ensure if java program uses UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, utf-8

I recently discovered that relying on default encoding of JVM causes bugs. I should explicitly use specific encoding ex. **UTF-8** while working with `String`, `InputStreams`  etc.
I have a huge codebase to scan for ensuring this. Could somebody suggest me some simpler way to check this than searching the whole codebase.

Thanks
Nayn

Comment: I read the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-default-charset-encoding-in-java

Comment: Are you specifying encoding other than utf8 somewhere?
By default strings in java is utf8 so i dont see a problem here.

Comment: @Imre: the problems will manifest whenever you read/write those characters as characters from/to an external source which expects/uses a different encoding (by default), e.g. the disk file system, a datastore (database), a network connection (HTTP), etc.

Comment: @Imre no, strings are not UTF-8 by default in Java. Strings consist  of 16-bit Unicode characters. If you read text from or write text to a file, those 16-bit Unicode characters will be encoded with a platform-dependent default character encoding. The default encoding is not always UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but to ease the job it's good to know that in a bit decent IDE you can just *search* for used occurrences of `InputStreamReader`, `OutputStreamWriter`, `String#getBytes()`, `String(byte[])`, `Properties#load()`, `URLEncoder#encode()`, `URLDecoder#decode()` and consorts wherein you could pass the charset and then update accordingly. You'd also like to search for `FileReader` and `FileWriter` and replace them by the first two mentioned classes. True, it's a tedious task, but worth it and I'd prefer it above relying on enrivonmental specifics.

In Eclipse for example, select the project(s) of interest, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, switch to tab *Java Search*, enter for example `InputStreamReader`, tick the *Search For* option *Constructor*, choose *Sources* as the only *Search In* option, and execute the search.

Comment: `FileReader` is the baddy. I don't know of a comprehensive list of these dangerous API methods/constructors.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

returns the VM encoding for i/o operations

You can set it by passing `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`

Comment: Please see the thread that i mentioned in the comment. The above property is internal implementation detail for specific JVM implementation. The use of this property is varying in Java 1.5 and 1.6.

Comment: it isn't. Read the accepted answer fully :) this is a standard setting that determines the default charset.

Comment: Setting a property like this to correct code is an outrageous hack.

Comment: @Tom I don't share your opinion on that. While it is preferable not to rely on this (and I never do), it is legitimate to use VM parameters.

Comment: I have to admit that I couldn't solve this problem without setting system property as -Dfile.encoding=utf-8. I tried every possible approach to put encoding wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

> relying on default encoding of JVM
>   causes bugs

Indeed, one should always specify the charset when encoding/decoding.

If you are satisfied a default global charset for all you encoding/decoding (not always enough), you can live with Bozho's answer : specify a known fixed default in your JVM arguments or in some static initializer.

But it's good practice to search all implicit charset specifications in your code, and replace them with a explicit charset encoding: some typical methods/classes to look at: `FileWriter`, `FileReader`, `InputStreamReader`, `OutputStreamWriter`, `String#getBytes()`, `String(byte[])`.

Comment: Noted should be that `FileWriter` and `FileReader` can't be changed to take a specified encoding. They should be replaced with `OutputStreamWriter` and `InputStreamReader` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is manipulated by native tools on the servers may want to set the encoding to System.getProperty("file.encoding").  I have run into bugs both ways.

Best practice is to know which character set is used, and set that. Also if the file is used to interface to another application, you should define the character set used.  This may be a windows code page or a different UTF format.