# Reading windows .CSV files in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, text, csv

I need to read and display some .csv files in my java application. The .csv files have some european special accented characters (french) that are displayed correctly when I run my app in Windows, but, when I run the app under Mac OS X, the special characters are corrupted. How can I keep and show my characters in both systems?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you are using different default charsets?

```
Charset.defaultCharset()
```

Here are two possible pointers:

[Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)

[How to Find the Default Charset/Encoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-default-charset-encoding-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The files are inside the application .jar, so, I am using .getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename")
to get an InputStream and load it in a InputStreamReader.