# Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence, but only when executing JAR?

Tags: java, windows, encoding, utf-8, xml-serialization

I have this java program where I transform with TransformerFactory a XML string that I get from a SQL Server database and write it to a file, and then use this file to generate a PDF.

The thing is that it works fine when I execute it with netbeans, but if I execute the jar in the project dist folder I get a "Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence".

*After changing the encoding of the XML string to UTF-8 now it works fine from the jar too.*

So my question is, why would it work when running the project in NetBeans but not from the JAR file before changing the encoding?

Have tried this only in Windows.

Code:

Here is the SQL Server query (original):

```
SQLXML xml = null;
String xmlString = "";
while (rs.next()){
    xml = rs.getSQLXML(1);
    xmlString = xml.getString();
}
return xmlString;
```

...and modified:

```
SQLXML xml = null;
String xmlString = "";
while (rs.next()){
    xml = rs.getSQLXML(1);
    // Note explicit UTF-8 encoding specified
    xmlString = new String(xml.getString().getBytes(),"UTF8");
 }
 return xmlString;
```

And here the transformation:

```
public static void serialize(Document doc, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        Transformer serializer = tfactory.newTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty("indent", "yes");
        serializer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        serializer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(out));
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you, by chance, using one of the conversion mechanisms that uses a "platform specific default encoding"? (e.g. it is assuming UTF-8 for something UTF-16.) And, is the JVM used the same in both instances? Posting the relevant code would be ... useful.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Added code now.

I'm not sure about that, what would one of those mechanisms be?

I think SQLServer returns the xml string unicode encoded, so that's why I get that error, but why would it work through netbeans without changing the encoding?

Comment: I bet a different JVM is being used in each case: can that proposition be confirmed or rejected?

Comment: That could be it! Thanks a lot, let me check this out and I'll get back to you. What would be the easiest way to confirm this?

Comment: I don't use netbeans :) But `java -version` should spit out useful things.

Comment: Ok :P I know I'm running 1.6.0.26 from command, but I'm still trying to find what netbeans is using. I wasn't even aware it could be using a different version.

Comment: I tested and it still doesn't work even when using same version :( I even reinstalled jdk and jre and change the jdk path in netbeans to make sure it was the same.

Comment: The plot thickens, I am out of ideas, but [How to Find Default Charset/Encoding in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064) indicates it is in a System property, which might be configured differently in one environment. This [article](http://wiki.clinicaltools.com/NetBeans:UTF-8_Character_Set) tells out to change the default encoding, in the NetBeans config (I am not sure if this is just for the IDE or also projects run from it :-)

Comment: If you [ever] get the issue figured out, don't forget to post a self-answer (and accept it) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried a simple Application in Netbeans that displays the [Charset.defaultCharset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), and it returns "UTF-8". The same one in Eclipse returns "MacRoman". I'm on a Mac, on Windows it'd return "cp-1252".

So yes, when you run an Application in Netbeans, it defaults to UTF-8 encoding, that's why you didn't have any issues when parsing the XML.