# Cyrillic characters, in utf8 file. Getting messed up

Tags: java, spring, unicode

I have in my integration test the following :

```
 myMap.put(Language.RU, "Египет");
```

which is then used as parameter, however when I do I sys out in my code (that uses the string accessed via the hashmap), it looks like this :

```
param is : РљР°РёСЂ%
```

Consequently there is no data returned, when in fact there should be when the original string is used to query the database.

I thought I was using utf-8 throughout, what could cause the problem ? Usign the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-default-charset-encoding-in-java), everything is indeed set to UTF-8 ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the encoding of your vm with -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: Its workign now, I think one of my files encoding was not utf-8 - somethign with my ide got borked I think. Thanks anyway