# JVM Charset.defaultCharset() does not return the expected charset

Tags: java, character-encoding, jvm, locale

My OS is windows 7 with Hebrew locale and using Java 6 in my code.
I've changed my locale to English(United States) and also the display language to English.
I restarted my PC and then in my java code tried to get the default charset as follow:

```
String str = Charset.defaultCharset().name();
```

The result, str is set to **windows-1255**.
Which means that it still using the Hebrew as the default charset.
What seems to be the problem?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-default-charset-encoding-in-java)  might answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by OpenJDK sources, `file.encoding` and thus `defaultCharset()` is set on Windows according to:

Java 6: [`GetUserDefaultLCID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function which corresponds to the Format option on the Formats tab of the Region and Language control panel applet.

Java 7: [`GetSystemDefaultLCID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function which corresponds to the "Language for non-Unicode programs" on the Administrative tab of the Region and Language control panel applet, unless you set the `sun.locale.formatasdefault` Java system property to `true`, which will revert to the Java 6 behavior.

So for Java 6 the Format is the setting to change.

Comment: Yes I did. In addition, I've changed also the language display to English in keyboards and Languages although it is not the setting that matters.

Comment: It works for me with Oracle's JDK 7 on Windows 7. Which is strange, because I looked up the OpenJDK sources for both Java 6 and 7 and the file.encoding system property (which is what `defaultCharset()` uses to determine the default charset) is set according to result of `GetUserDefaultLCID` Win32 function, corresponding to the Format option on the Formats tab of the Region and Language control panel applet, not the `GetSystemDefaultLCID` which is the "Language for non-Unicode programs". Could you try changing the "Format" as well to see if there's any change? I'll correct my answer then.

Comment: You are absolutly right! When I changed the Format I got the correct default Charset.