# A square [_] between my text and my picture in my Jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I created a file `.txt` which contains a sentence.

**I want to set a Jlabel with this sentence and a picture .gif**

So I did this :

(I declared 2 Strings with the path to my .txt and the path to my picture)

Then I asked to set it:

```
{
        ZoneAlerte1 = new JLabel();
        getContentPane().add(ZoneAlerte1);
        ZoneAlerte1.setText(new UTIL_LireFichierTXT().getText(MessageTest)); 
        ZoneAlerte1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma",0,12));
        ZoneAlerte1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Icon));   
        ZoneAlerte1.setBounds(400, 200, 300, 40);
        ZoneAlerte1.setVisible(true);


}
```

The thing is: when I run my programm, the Label contains the picture and my text but **there's a little square between them**, like if there were some unknown character in my sentence.

So I tried to replace this line:

`ZoneAlerte1.setText(new UTIL_LireFichierTXT().getText(MessageTest));` by `ZoneAlerte1.setText("hello");`

And it works perfectly, without the square

Then I guess the problem comes from this method called to read a .txt :

```
public class UTIL_LireFichierTXT {
    public String chaine="";
    public String fichier ="";
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }


public String getText(String path){
            fichier=path;

        //lecture du fichier texte  
        try
        {
            InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(fichier); 
            InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
            String ligne;
            while ((ligne=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                //System.out.println(ligne);
                chaine+=ligne+"\n";
            }
            br.close(); 
            //System.out.println(chaine);
            return chaine;
        }       
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return chaine;

        }
    }
```

The problem doesn't come from my .txt or the label because when I do the exact same thing (setting my text without setting in a picture), it works without a square.

Actually it's pretty strange because:

`Jlabel` + this method to set `.txt`: **no square**

`Jlabel` + picture + this method: **square**

`Jlabel` + picture: **no square**

`Jlabel` + picture + `set.Text("Hello!")`: **square**

Thanks in advance.

PS : I used a `Jlabel` instead of a `JTextPane` because I needeed transparency.

Comment: It's too long no ? I'm sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely that this is because the file is not in the charset that Java expects. The InputStreamReader constructor can accept a Charset to bypass the platform default. Using

```
Charset.forName(...)
```

as an argument you can try different ones and see if something works (the standard charsets can be found in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)).

Alternatively, you can investigate this issue with Notepad++ under windows (and tons of other editors, just my personal favorite) to display your text with different charsets and convert if necessary.

The default charset of the JVM is returned by

```
Charset.defaultCharset()
```

with some caveats depending on your version (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-default-charset-encoding-in-java)).

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered what was wrong.

When I delete the line which set the font tahoma, it works without a square !! I don't know why but this font doesn't allow me to set a picture and a text in my JLabel.

I think that you gave the correct answer but I didn't find anything wrong with my .txt in notepad++

Thanks.