# How do I get the character encoding of the currently running JVM?

Tags: java, character-encoding, jvm

I have an issue where I think my local JVM is running with a different character encoding to one that runs on a server.  Is there a command I can pass to the vm to display what character encoding is has?  Something like

java show 'charset'

I've been searching for ages, and all of the solutions require writing a test in java code, but I don't really want to have to write code, deploy it to the server, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Find the Default Charset/Encoding in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-the-default-charset-encoding-in-java)

Comment: May be try to use jvisualvm to check JVM properties