# Apache Common FileUtils readLines method ambiguous call

Tags: android, apache, io, readlines, fileutils

I stumbled upon this problem when trying to play around with Apache commons IO third party API with Android Studio.

Basically when I try to call the **FileUtils.readLines()** method, there are 3 options:

- **readLines(File file)** >>>> ***DEPRECATED***
- **readLines(File file, String encoding)**
- **readLines(File file, Charset encoding)**

The first option has already been deprecated which means that I shouldn't use it anymore so instead I just type **readLines(file,null)** However, right now the problem is that Android Studio doesn't know which readLines() method signature I'm using because **readLines(file,null)** is valid for both the second and third method signature.

Screenshot below to further explain what I mean:

[image]

Can anyone please enlighten me on this? How can I tell Android Studio the particular method signature that I want to use for **FileUtils.readLines()**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDE can't guess what your null is. Whether it is String or Charset. You can try something like:

```
String encoding=null;
FileUtils.readLines(file, encoding);
```

But I think that wouldn't work since `readLines` method needs to know what encoding your file uses. So if for example your file uses UTF-8, you can write this

```
FileUtils.readLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Or you can try to use default charset, see this:
[How to Find the Default Charset/Encoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-the-default-charset-encoding-in-java)

And as Apache docs say, deprecated version readLines(File file) used default charset. You can write this to get an equivalent:

```
FileUtils.readLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that mate! Ohhhh I see, yeah I tried your suggestion with the **Charset.defaultCharset()** and it works haha. I also tried doing the **String encoding = null; FileUtils.readLines(file,encoding)** but yeah that doesn't work. 

Thanks so much!