# How to distinguish Java on z/OS from Java on Linux on z/OS?

Tags: java, zos

Is Java on z/OS and Java on Linux on IBM Z systems distinguishable from each other by `os.name` and/or `os.arch` properties? What about UNIX services for z/OS, does it have distinctive Java distribution?

**Update 1**

My understanding is that z/OS uses dot or colon (?) as path component separator while Unix-like subsystem uses solidus. My expectation is that there is Java for z/OS which uses whatever native C library and executable file format z/OS has, using the dot/colon as separator, while z/OS UNIX subsystem and Linux on IBM Z use POSIX compatible C library and use ELF as executable format. I would expect there to be two different JREs, one for the z/OS Linux and another for the z/OS UNIX service subsystem. My expectation is that the `EI_OSABI` field in ELF file format header is distinct for Linux and for z/OS UNIX subsystem, thus there should be two different Java distributions.

Is there z/OS Java which runs outside any of the Unix-like subsystems?

Comment: Why do you ask? Beware the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Thomas: I am aware of XY problem. There are branches in our code that invoke the `ps` utility on Unix-like OS which will not work on z/OS but will work on Linux on z/OS. There is also the encoding stuff, we transocde some text files into EBCDIC but not for Linux, etc.

Comment: You could do feature detection on `ps` by trying some commands until one of them works (or stick to a known supported subset, e.g. POSIX, if possible). You could look at the [default charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-the-default-charset-encoding-in-java) to find out what encoding to use. Not saying this is the solution, just maybe providing another angle on the problem.

Comment: Or switch the behaviour depending on some configuration, e.g. through environment variables. Again, not saying that is _the_ solution.

Comment: @wilx Can you be more specific why the "ps" utility should not work z/OS? z/OS is an XOpen and Posix compliant UNIX system besides the legacy "MVS" system

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by "dot or colon as path component separator". The word "path" implies the UNIX files system of z/OS, and this is no different to other UNIX systems: The (forward) slash is the single separator. You don't talk about MVS data sets, so you? And when it comes to executable formats: They are called "program objects", and are a different format.

Comment: @phunsoft: I admit I am confused. I do not have any experience with z/OS whatsover, so my assumptions are incorrect. But I still don't understand how can there be a single binary of JRE that runs on both Linux on IBM Z systems and on z/OS UNIX subsystem.

Comment: Can you elaborate what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I didn't say there is a single binary. My statement was related to z/OS. I understood you were asking if there is a Java for z/OS, and a Java for z/OS Unix. There is only one. There is a different Java (binary) for zLinux. Binaries are not exchangable between z/OS and zLinux.

Comment: @wilx Just saw that the title still sais "Linux on z/OS". Would you mind changing that to "Linux on Z Systems*, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to give an overview of how *Linux*, especially *Linux on Z Systems* and *z/OS* are different (or not). I'll need to simplify a lot to be able to keep it reasonably short.

Update 1: Changed some wording to be more clear, and corrected typos.

## Linux, and Linux on Z Systems

Linux is a UNIX-like operating systen that was first developed for Intel based systems (I think). Later, it became available for other hardware platforms, IBM Z Systems hardware being one of them. The Linux which runs on IBM mainframe hardware, or *IBM Z Systems*, is called *Linux for System Z*, or *Linux on IBM Z*; I'll call it *zLinux* hereafter for brevity.

Linux is Linux, no matter what platform it runs on. This is mostly true for: How you install it, how you configure it, how you run it, what API is provides, etc. Differences might exist when it comes to hardware configuration, or booting. This is especially true for zLinux.

Since the APIs are the same across, it offers source code portability, on an *application level*. And I consider the Java JVM an application in this context. Simplified this means, you take the source code, run it through the compiler that produces binaries for the target platform, and you're done.

What you optionally can do, is code optimization for the target platform, possibly to spead up things. In that sense the Java JVM for zLinux might work differently under the covers than the Java JVM for, say, an Intel PC platform (I actually don't know, if this is the case or not). But this would not matter to Java applications.

### Running Programs on UNIX (e.g. Linux)

A program running on a UNIX system runs as *process*. Simplified, the term *process* includes control structures, and the virtual address space (memory, process image). To run another program, some program already running needs to fork(), then exec(). This will create a new process for that program.

The UNIX kernel does process management (programs runs as process), dispatching/undispatching onto/from a processor, memory management, file system management, priority management, user and group management using numeric uid, and numeric gid, etc., etc.

## z/OS

z/OS is one of IBM's mainframe operating systems, which run on IBM Z Systems hardware. Though running on Z Systems, like zLinux does, z/OS has not much in common with a Linux, or UNIX system. Installation, configuration, and running z/OS couldn't be more different.

### z/OS MVS (without z/OS UNIX System Services)

*MVS*, born in 1964, is a component, or part, of any z/OS system. Its kind of like what the kernel is to a UNIX system. MVS provides the APIs that programs running on z/OS call. I call such a program *an MVS program* here. These APIs, again, are completely different to UNIX APIs. So, even though the hardware is the same, binaries are not exchangable. You cannot easily port a UNIX program into a z/OS MVS program; you have to rewrite from scratch.

*MVS* does task management (programs run as tasks), dispatching/undispatching onto/from a processor, memory management, data set management (MVS does not understand "UNIX file system"), priority management, user and group management using alphanumeric userid, and alphanumeric groupname, etc. etc.

### z/OS UNIX System Services

In the early 1990s, IBM wanted to make it easier to port popular UNIX programs to z/OS, so the added UNIX APIs, and called this part (finally) *z/OS UNIX System Services*, short *z/OS UNIX* hereafter. This came out in 1994. z/OS UNIX is another component of z/OS (also called *OMVS*). It is *not* a full UNIX kernel, but only adds to *MVS* what is required by UNIX, what MVS does not aleady have, foremost, process management, numeric uid, and gid, and a UNIX-like file system.

IBM added everything required to become an xOpen and Posix compliant operating system. Now, you don't have to rewrite the UNIX program to run it on z/OS, you can more or less easily port it. There still are differences to cope with, foremost the dreadfull EBCDIC - ASCII difference. But API calls are 1:1, provided the program only uses compliant APIs.

### Running Programs on z/OS

There are three kinds of programs:

1. Programs that know nothing about UNIX, only use the MVS APIs, and deal with MVS data sets for I/O. Let's call them *MVS programs*.
2. Programs that were ported from UNIX, or written by someone who only knows UNIX, which know nothing about MVS, only use the UNIX APIs, and deal with UNIX directoies and files for I/O. Let's call them *pure z/OS UNIX programs*. (Well, this category does nor really exist, see *) below).
3. Programs that know both MVS, and z/OS UNIX, which call MVS, and z/OS UNIX APIs, and deal with MVS data sets, as well as with UNIX directories, and files. Let's call them *mixed mode pograms*.

*) Every program needs memory, and every program wants to become dispateched on the processor eventually. Memory management, and task management is provided by MVS, not the UNIX kernel, so unknowingly, the program calls MVS APIs under the covers. Conclusion: There is no such thing as a "pure z/OS UNIX program". That leaves us with categories 1 and 3, only.

All of those programs are stored as *program objects*, and reside either as member in a *load library* (data set), or as file in the UNIX file system. When run, the executable is loaded from either source in to an MVS address space, and is started as a *task*. All programs are managed as MVS tasks, have got all the MVS attributes, plus in case 3 above, also have UNIX attrributes (process id, uid, gid, etc).

A program of type 1, becomes type 3 at runtime as soon as it makes a call to a UNIX API. So, there is no such thing as a wall, or boundary, or subsystem. It's all MVS programs, that may also be UNIX programs at the same time.

### Java on z/OS

The Java JVM that runs on z/OS is no exception. It has been ported to z/OS, and since this was easier, as z/OS UNIX program (well "mixed mode program", as you should know by now). It has been optimized for the hardware *and* the specifics of z/OS in many aspects. But to Java applications it is not different. Java applications are not binaries, so the same Java byte-code runs on any Java JVM (with exceptions).