# How to convert this string format to proper format?

Tags: java, string, unicode

Right now I have JSON data, and it has things in it like follows:

```
\u00e9
```

How can I change its format so that can be expressed normally as an "é"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u00e9")`

Comment: Succesfully converted my JSON string from escaped to unescaped, created new JSONObject and it all worked fine.

Comment: When I use this Java statement: System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u00e9"));  I get the character "Ž" on my MacBook Pro running OS X with a command-line terminal. Anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether you are using any JSON tools, but some of them have support for this kind of escape handling. If you're processing it yourself, there's not much you can do other than parse the escape sequence yourself. There are various ways to do it (including using regular expressions), but this is pretty simple to do directly. Just look for the "\u" prefix, take the next four characters and parse them as a hex integer. Then cast the result to a `char` and use that in place of the six original characters.

Comment: There is parser built already by Apache folks. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters in Java are considered literals. For example,

```
String foo = "\u00e9";
```

is considered a literal character `é`. Having said that, does this sample program give you any ideas?

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myCharacter = "\u00e9";
        System.out.println(myCharacter);
    }
}
```

Have a look at [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode).

Comment: OP is trying to process Unicode-escaped characters present in JSON data, not write Java code containing Unicode literals.

Comment: Oh, that's right - from information presented by OP and tags, suggest that they are writing code in Java to process JSON data.

Comment: What does this have to do with the original question? No, the sample program doesn't give any ideas.